# How to Reset Bindings in C#

Tags: c#

```
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbProductName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text))
        {
            Receipt obj = new Receipt() { Id = order++, ProductName = Convert.ToString(cmbProductName.SelectedItem), Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text), Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text) };
            total += Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
            receiptBindingSource.Add(obj);
            receiptBindingSource.MoveLast();
            Clear();           
        }
        txtTotal.Text = String.Format("P{0}", Convert.ToString(total));

    }
        private void refresh() {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = receiptBindingSource;

    }
```

anyone can help me what code should I use to reset my bindings. because when click on new button. The computation of product still continue. Im making a billing system. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the binding in the XAML(View) set the datacontext of the view to your viewmodel(class) and set the binding to variables(with get/set accessors) inside your class.

Comment: a noteworthy read for you to get started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx

Comment: How? can you wrote an example code please? thank you. im sorry. im a beginner in c#

Comment: Add dataGridView1.DataBind(); This will bind the data to your control each time it runs. If your method runs again it should automatically rebinds data from your assigned datasource. Providing datasource is not empty.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers :)

Comment: @FritzJimenez added a length explaination for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very basic overview of what you are going to have to do

***Imagine the Textbox is your datagrid***

**Your XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
</TextBox>
<Button Margin="10,0,10,0" Width="100" Content="New" >
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <ei:CallMethodAction 
             TargetObject="{Binding}"
             MethodName="OnNewClicked"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

***Your content is its text***

**Codebehind of your XAML page(View)**

```
public CodeBehindOfYourXAML()
{
  YourViewModel dataContext = new YourViewModel();
  this.DataContext = dataContext;
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

***The datacontext is the class you have all your variables in***
, here you are binding your View(XAML) and your ViewModel(class)

**Your ViewModel**

```
using SimpleMvvmToolkit;

namespace LocationToNamespace.Derp
{
    public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase<YourViewModel>
    {
        private string _selectedValue;
        public string SelectedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedValue;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedValue);
            }
        }
        public void OnNewClicked()
        {
            SelectedValue = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

The viewmodel contains all your data you can now simply bind to your datagrid(textbox in this case)

and whenever you make a change to your datagrid(textbox in this case) it will automatically be updated by the combonation of

```
NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedValue);//viewmodel
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged //XAML
```

**NOTE** download the nuget package "SimpleMvvmToolkit" <-- its used in the viewmodel

Comment: Note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. While firing `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` on the binding source triggers an update of the binding target, `UpdateSourceTrigger` controls how a Binding triggers an update of the source property when the target property has changed. Hence it is only effective when the Binding Mode is TwoWay or OneWayToSource. Its default value dependends on the target dependency property and usually is `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: You usually only set `UpdateSourceTrigger` when the default value is different (e.g. `LostFocus` as for the `TextBox.Text` property), but you still want that the source is updated on every change of the target property (e.g. every key stroke in a TextBox).

Comment: @Clemens its not INotifyPropertyChanged though, its SimpleMvvmToolkit's Notifypropertychanged event.

Comment: @Clemens but i do agree

Comment: From the [SimpleMvvmToolkit sources](https://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/VS2013/Common/SimpleMvvmToolkit-Common/ViewModelBaseCore.cs): `public abstract class ViewModelBaseCore<TViewModel> : INotifyPropertyChanged`. If it wasn't INotifyPropertyChanged, WPF wouldn't understand it.